# how to get input from UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, uikit

I want take player name as input by using UIAlertView. Is it possible to add textField on the UIAlertView?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible, and it isn't a hack. You would need to subclass UIAlertView and place controls into it. Since it's a subclass, it will retain the same look & feel, etc.

For full details, see [this tutorial](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/alert-view-with-prompt.html) by Jeff LaMarche (co-author of Beginning iPhone Development, from Apress).

Answer (score 31):

Since iOS 5, UIAlertView provides this: change the alertViewStyle property to one of the following:

```
UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput (1 text field)
UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput (1 password field)
UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput (both a text field and password field)
```

Then use `textFieldAtIndex:` to get the text field you want. This way, you can even use the `alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:` delegate method to enable the button.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not without some hacking, see this [previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551530/customizing-uialertview)
 You'd have to directly manipulate the UIAlertView's subviews and add a UITextField and then resize the UIAlertView's frame. You're better off creating your own view.