# How to add text in multiple lines in message field of UIAlertView

Tags: iphone

```
    The AlertView should look like this.



 AlertView Message:


     Please provide one of the following parameters to find the doctors.
                     Speciality
                     Location
                     Insurance
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `\n` for a line break.

```
... message:@"1st line of message\n2nd line of message\n\n\n5th line of message" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The UIAlertView can be cusomised :

Some info here
[Customizing UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551530/customizing-uialertview)

and here
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1704-uitextfield-inside-uialertview.html

However, I think what you want is to build a custom view, or (more simply) use an UIActionSheet - that's the device designed for the purpose!