# Xcode 4.2, UIAlertView and UIAlertButton?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uialertview

after I update Xcode from 4.1 to 4.2, UIAlertView's others button can't display correctly.
[image: UIAlertView in Xcode 4.2]

and when I debug, the Rename button is UIAlertButton class and its frame is frame = (0 0; 0 0);
could you give a hand?

Comment: Is this really an UIAlertView, or some subclass or replacing?

Comment: Can you post you alert view setup code.

Comment: According to the HIG, we are not supposed to have UITextFields on the AlertView

Comment: @ShantiKamichetty it changed in iOS 5, now several styles are supported, including TextInput http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006802-CH3-SW14

Comment: @shanti kamichetty, are you sure?

Comment: @Brogrammer he is right for iOS < 5. That was quite funny, as Apple also always used alerts with input.

Comment: @vikingosegundo it is a subclass of UIAlertView, add a UITextFields on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIAlertView just behave very badly when being subclassed. Apple seems to try to make it nearly impossible to subclass it.

But there are ways around it. The best one: A UIAlertView replacement — a view, that recreates the features of UIAlertView, without being one. [TSAlertView](https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView) is such a replacement.

For iOS 5 the [`alertViewStyle`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006802-CH3-SW14) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fast way to fix that may like it's:

```
alert = [[YourSubclassOfUIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Change my name"
message:@"From now on, I want to know as:\n\n"  /* Add \n\n to expand the UIAlertView space */ delegate:.....
```

BTW: @vikingosegundo was right.
And you will find this post usefull: [Customizing UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551530/customizing-uialertview)