# Move buttons down in UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

I have an app which displays in landscape mode and I've overwritten the height of a `UIAlertView` with the following code:

```
- (void) willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect frame = [alertView frame];
    alertView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, 0, frame.size.width, screenBounds.size.width);
}
```

This almost works. The `UIAlertView` is taller, however, the buttons in the alertview don't get pushed down.

Does anyone know how I can push the buttons in a `UIAlertView` down when I change the alert view's height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is more elegant and less risky to replace UIAlertView with some independent AlertView instead of messing around with it.With independent I mean not inheriting form UIAlertView.
[TSAlertView](https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView) is such a replacement.

[http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47535/TSAlertView/1-thumb.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47535/TSAlertView/1.png)
[http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47535/TSAlertView/3-thumb.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47535/TSAlertView/3.png)
[http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47535/TSAlertView/2-thumb.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47535/TSAlertView/2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you'll probably have to subclass / manipulate the UIAlertView class to achieve that, which can be risky as Apple can change their implementations so wrap your code in appropriate checks.

A start would be to do:

```
NSLog(@"UIAlertView subviews: %@",alertView.subviews);
```

That'll print some output for the various elements making up the UIAlertView, you will probably see a few UIButtons in there which you can then manipulate by using something like:

```
UIButton* button1 = (UIButton*)[alertView.subviews objectAtIndex:N];
[button1 setFrame:CGRect(button1.frame.origin.x, button1.frame.origin.y+10, button1.frame.size.width, button1.frame.size.height)]
```

A sensible check would be to confirm that the objectAtIndex is the correct type of element before you perform operations on it, this isn't foolproof however as Apple could add more UIButtons or something..

```
if ([[alertView.subviews objectAtIndex:N] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
  ...
}
```

Depending on your situation you may also want to iterate over the subviews array and move all UIButtons down rather than just hardcoding in some specific objectsAtIndex but that's a whole other answer. :-)

Comment: Valid points, but it may lead to App Store rejection due to messing around with the Alert View class. By the way, love the username.

Comment: Agreed that altering them is risky, but since you'd covered that I thought I'd provide a possible way of doing it. You never know, perhaps it's a closed release :-).

Comment: You should add this into your answer, because it took me about an hour to figure this one out: When resetting the frame of a button for a subclassed UIAlertView, you must reset it in the `layoutSubviews` method of your class, not in the `initWithTitle...` method.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551530/customizing-uialertview) should help. In my opinion, I would not try messing around with the view hierarchies. This can lead to rejection from the App Store. Either build a new AlertView from scratch, or leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

NSArray *subViewArray=[alertView subviews];

```
for (NSUInteger ind=0 ; ind < [subViewArray count]; ind++) {

    if ([[alertView.subviews objectAtIndex:ind] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton* button1 = (UIButton*)[alertView.subviews objectAtIndex:ind];
        [button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(button1.frame.origin.x, button1.frame.origin.y+100, button1.frame.size.width, button1.frame.size.height)];
        NSLog(@"button1.frame.origin.y=[%1.0f]",button1.frame.origin.y);

    }
}
```