# UIAlertView with 3 buttons > spacing on third button

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

I am creating a simple alert view with 3 buttons, each button has equal importance, there is no cancel button or anything like that:

```
UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"msg" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"button1",@"button2",@"button3",nil];
[alert show];
```

The third button has extra space above it, as if it was a cancel button.
I would like the space to be identical in between buttons.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do so (you'd have to literally reinvent the wheel, subclassing UIAlertView [not necessarily being a very viable option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551530/customizing-uialertview)).

However, you might be interested by the [BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets](https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets) library, that would give you nice, block based, alert views that do offer a consistent spacing between buttons.

Comment: thanks for the library link, could be useful at some point. That's very unfortunate that there isn't an easier way to do this, they introduced the login/password style for alertviews in iOS5, who knows what comes in a few weeks with iOS6...