# Custom view which looks like UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need something what looks like `UIAlertView` (same background transparent and not full screen), blocks other UI parts and has some custom content.
This custom content are: two check-boxes with labels and two buttons YES/NO at the bottom.

Sub-classing or customizing `UIAlertView` doesn't looks useful (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/552396/1387438)) and it is dangerous (code can be rejected by Apple). I was thinking to create own custom `UIView` (possible with `UIViewController`), but I have no idea how to make it look and feel like UIAlertView. I mean I'd like to make it that it changes its appearance dependent on iOS version (iOS7).

**update**:
I can abandon os version dependency, it would be nice to have, but this is additional feature.
The main question is: is there a good way to make such view which will look and feel like UIAlertView without large amount of work? Customizing `UIAlertView` directly looks complicated and dangerous.

Comment: While this is perfectly possible, I'd recommend finding a less intrusive and less complicated way to do this. Something like this is a reasonable amount of work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I created my own custom view to look like iOS UIAlertView 7. With that technique you can create a custom alert for both iOS 6 and iOS 7.
For that, I created a UIView in my xib file of my UIViewController :

[image]

I added some @property for this view :

```
// Custom iOS 7 Alert View
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *supportViewPopup; // My UIView
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *supportViewPopupBackground; // The grey view
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *supportViewPopupAction; // The white view with outlets
// Property for customize the UI of this alert (you can add other labels, buttons, tableview, etc.
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonOK;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonCancel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *labelDescription;
```

On my viewDidLoad :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

       // Support View
    self.supportViewPopupAction.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    self.supportViewPopupAction.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    // Add Support View
    [self.view addSubview:self.supportViewPopup];

    // Center Support view
    self.supportViewPopup.center = self.view.center;

    // Alpha
    self.supportViewPopup.alpha = 0.0f;
    self.supportViewPopupBackground.alpha = 0.0f;
    self.supportViewPopupAction.alpha = 0.0f;
}
```

Action to display Popup :

```
- (IBAction)displayPopup
{
    // Support View
    self.supportViewPopup.alpha = 1.0f;
    self.supportViewPopupBackground.alpha = 0.5f;

    // Animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                     animations:^{
                         self.supportViewPopupAction.alpha = 1.0f;
                     }];
}
```

Action to dismiss Popup :

```
- (IBAction)dismissModal
{
    // Animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                     animations:^{
                         self.supportViewPopup.alpha = 0.0f;
                         self.supportViewPopupBackground.alpha = 0.0f;
                         self.supportViewPopupAction.alpha = 0.0f;
                     }];
}
```

So, with that you can configure your `supportViewPopupAction` like you want with buttons, table view, labels, collection view, etc...

I spent time to write this example of alert view. I hope this will help you !

Comment: But the `UILabel` does not resize itself as it does in `UIAlertView`

Comment: to do that you need to play with auto-layout and auto-sizing :)

Comment: How did you make the button lines?

Comment: Nevermind... Got it... Are the the extra views... 1px wide... clever... very clever...

Comment: I was looking for better solution for a long time, but looks like that multiple xib files for each look and feel is only good solution. Thanks.

Comment: @RaphaelAyres The Lines can be made with a UIView with 1 Pixel height or width, depending on your needs.

Comment: Henceforth, you can now use UIAlertController. Nice update by Apple ;)

Comment: this is not a UIAlertView like, you need do add the view to the controller, the power of alert view is you don't need to give him the context(view controller in our case) the only thing you need to do in alertview is call "show", so you can call it from anywhere.

Comment: Can I have complete source code of this program? because in side menus it showing something like in storyboard, whereas in answer it stated "UIVIew in my xib file", and in our xib file it does not shows view's hierarchy, So I just wants to see the views and subviews hierarchy and their connections. If I've its source code(complete code along with xib or storyboard) it'll be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's from 2013! I do not have this code anymore... sorry

Answer (score 1):

Custom views can be passed to PXAlertView: https://github.com/alexanderjarvis/PXAlertView

Answer (score 0):

Some components as UIButtons and UITextFields are going to look different depending on the version, so that's going to be fine, the problem I see is going to be in the view that contains then.

My suggestion is to detect the version where the app is running and then draw the alert view based on that, or just create a custom design that will fit both.

Answer (score 0):

Creat view depending on the iOS versions!

```
NSString *version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
        int major = [version intValue];
        if (major < 7)
            //alert for the iOS 6
    else
    //alert for the iOS 7
```

Comment: this is crappy way of checking iOS version. There is better way: `NSFoundationVersionNumber` see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW144). Anyway this approach requires lots of manual coding.