# How to make a custom alert ease in/out when displaying?

Tags: ios, animation

I've got a custom alert dialog based on TSAlertView (https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView)

However when it gets displayed its appearance is very sudden and jarring, I tried adding some animation to it using the following code however it makes no difference (the following code has no effect at all, I could change the duration to N seconds or change the animation style to anything and it has no impact):

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                  duration: 0.5
                   options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                animations:^ { [self.view addSubview:dialog]; }
                completion:nil];
```

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118919/custom-view-which-looks-like-uialertview/19119307#19119307

Comment: `addSubview` is not an animatable property (or method).

Comment: Thanks. That code I copied from an accepted SO answer, but I've forgotton which so can't go back and comment that its incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding the alert view as a subview in the animations block try changing it's alpha value. When you create the the AlertView set the alpha to zero and add it as a subview. Then, in the animation block, change the alpha value to one.

Hope this helps!