# Alternative to UIALertView for user input ios7

Tags: ios7, uialertview, subview

Ok, we assume that now we can't add subviews in AlertViews since ios7. But when we need to popup a new little view for the user to input some data, what we have to do ? What apple says we have to do now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom alert.

I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118919/custom-view-which-looks-like-uialertview/19119307#19119307) a way how to do that.

Comment: Yes, but it has no sense... Has IOS7 another view where we can add subviews for user input ?

Comment: No sense ? Here you add a new view and you add what you want inside this view, textfields, labels, button, collectionview, etc. and you pop-up this view with an animation like a UIAlertView

Comment: Of course, your view is good. But I mean... seems thatinstead of moving forward, we're going back with ios 7. With ios6 we could do an input from the user very quick with few lines, now we need to write lot of code for the same ...

Comment: Yep so bad. You can have a look here : https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController

Comment: I was trying with it https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview ... but it only supports ios7 . I want compatibility with ios6 as well. Then I get errors.