# Simple UIAlertView with NSAttributedString(s)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, nsattributedstring

I am looking for a simple way to use `NSAttributedString` with a very simple message box similar to:

```
NSString *new_item = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span style=\"font-family: Helvetica Neue; font-size: 12.0\">%@</span>", @"MOTD HTML String downloaded from website"];
NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[new_item dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MOTD"
                                                   message:attrStr
                                                  delegate:nil
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

My above code takes a HTML formatted string that has been downloaded from a server, makes sure the text size will fit the screen properly, then tries to send the `NSAttributedString` to the `UIAlertView`. But `UIAlertView` does not like this. what would be the simplest way around this problem?(Non HTML formatted MOTD is not an option)

Comment: Neither `UIAlertView` nor `UIAlertController` work with attributed strings. Either find a 3rd party replacement that does or write your own.

Comment: any suggestion on what 3rd party lib to use? I was looking on cocoa controls but all of them seem way more complicated then what I'm looking for

Comment: Guess the best way would be to create my own, good example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118919/custom-view-which-looks-like-uialertview/19119307#19119307

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add your attributed string to label and add it as assessoryView to alert

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Test Attributed String" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Hello red"];
[attributedStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
lbl.attributedText = attributedStr;
lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[alert setValue:lbl forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[alert show];
```

Now a days `UIAlertView` is deprecated. You can use `UIAlertController`.

Comment: This achieves what I'm trying to do, may need to worry about sizing for long messages. Thanks!

Comment: @AshishKakkad, TY for your answer – I have found a way to improve its UI. +1 for you and some contribution to the SO from my side. `[P.S. added my own answer]`

Comment: @NiibFouda Welcome. But please use `UIAlertController`

Comment: @AshishKakkad I couldn't use "accessoryView" with  UIAlertController 
I ned to add a clickable hyperlink in an alert

Answer (score 5):

I got an idea from the @AshishKakkad answer only (+1). However, its UI isn't properly visible. So I'm showing you a way to format your message with `attributedString`.

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
NSMutableString *message = [NSMutableString string];
NSString *title = @"Message Heading";
[message appendString:title];
[message appendString:@"\n\n• Topic 1"];
[message appendString:@"\n• Topic 2"];
[message appendString:@"\n• Topic 3\n"]; //Important, I have added '\n' at last to have some extra space at bottom.

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"CancelButton" otherButtonTitles:@"OtherButton", nil];
//need to set a label as `accessoryView` of an alert.
[alert setValue:[self getLabelWithMessage:message withTitle:title] forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[alert show];
```

---

```
- (UILabel *)getLabelWithMessage:(NSMutableString *)message withTitle:(NSString *)title {
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 2.0f;
    paragraphStyle.headIndent = 20.0;
    paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 20.0;
    paragraphStyle.tailIndent = -20.0;

    NSMutableAttributedString *attribString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:message];
    [attribString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [message length])];
    [attribString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.f] range:NSMakeRange(0, [message length])];
    [attribString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.f] range:NSMakeRange(0, [title length])];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [label setAttributedText:attribString];
    [label setNumberOfLines:0];
    [label sizeToFit];
    return label;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

don't forget to set:

lbl.numberOfLines = 0;

when you have multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to private API you could use https://github.com/AntonPoltoratskyi/NativeUI

`pod 'NativeUI/Alert', '~> 1.0'`

It looks exactly like native alert, but configurable enough.

Please look https://stackoverflow.com/a/61047809/6726766 for more details.