# UIAlertcontroller set attributed messages

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

How we can set Attributed text in UIAlertcontroller as message. 
My try code As bellow, but it will crash the app.

```
// create Attributed text

let myAttribute = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red:122.0/255, green:125.0/255, blue:131.0/255, alpha:1.0),NSFontAttributeName: Constant.flinntRegularFont(15)]
let myAttribute2 = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),NSFontAttributeName: Constant.flinntMediumFont(15)]

let myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "You have been unsubscribed from ", attributes: myAttribute)
let myString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.course.course_name, attributes: myAttribute2)
let myString3 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\n\nYour refund will be initiated within one week.", attributes: myAttribute)
let myString4 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\n\nFor any help call us on", attributes: myAttribute)
let myString5 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " 079-4014 9800", attributes: myAttribute2)
let myString6 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " between 9:30 am to 6:30 pm on Monday to Saturday.\n\nWe will be always here with great deals to share.", attributes: myAttribute)

myString.appendAttributedString(myString2)
myString.appendAttributedString(myString3)
myString.appendAttributedString(myString4)
myString.appendAttributedString(myString5)
myString.appendAttributedString(myString6)
```

Present UIAlertcontroller Code

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Select course", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.setValue(myAttribute, forKey: "attributedMessage") // this line make a crash.

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action) in
        self.delegate?.courseRefundViewControllerCoursrRefunded?(self)
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIAlertController custom font, size, color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color)

Comment: You cannot pass the `attributedString` to `UIAlertController` without using the *private API*.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You app is crashing because of DataType mismatch.

`alert.setValue(<value>, forKey: "attributedMessage")`

Here `<value>` must be an instance of `NSMutableAttributedString`.

But you are passing myAttribute Which is `Dictionary`.

It is trying ta call `length` method but it is not found on `Dictionary` thats why app is crashing.

Try this:

```
alert.setValue(myString, forKey: "attributedMessage")
```

Comment: Thanks @CRDave for your help.

Comment: thanks. it's worrisome this is not exposed explicitly and you have to do this blind flight dance in the first place :-[

Comment: filed 51171348 with apple to remove the need fo this kludge

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer here works as of iOS 15, but if Apple ever changes their private api this would crash without warning. What's ironic is that historically it's when they make this kind of api public that it changes and breaks things like this. Here is a way to use the private api safely:

```swift
if
    let property = class_getProperty(type(of: alert), "attributedMessage"),
    let type = property_copyAttributeValue(property, "T"),
    String(cString: type) == #"@"NSAttributedString""#
{
    alert.setValue(myString, forKey: "attributedMessage")
} else {
    alert.message = myString.string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to private API you could use https://github.com/AntonPoltoratskyi/NativeUI

`pod 'NativeUI/Alert', '~> 1.0'`

It is a custom view controller that was implemented from scratch and looks exactly like native `UIAlertController`.

You could pass either `String`, `NSAttributedString` or custom content view.

```swift
let viewModel = Alert(
    title: "Your Title",
    message: nil,
    contentView: customView,
    actions: [cancelAction, confirmAction]
)
let alert = AlertViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
present(alert, animated: true)
```