# iOS: How to change every font of each text, title, buttons of alertView in my application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uiappearance

I already implanted a code that allows 99% of the font of my application to some specific fonts:

```
@implementation UILabel(SizedFontName) //APPEARANCE
- (void)setSizedFontName:(id)test UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR
{
    NSString *fontName = self.font.fontName;
    CGFloat fontSize = self.font.pointSize;

    if ([[fontName lowercaseString] rangeOfString:@"bold"].location != NSNotFound || [[fontName lowercaseString] rangeOfString:@"fb"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:nameFontBold size:fontSize];
    }
    else if ([[fontName lowercaseString] rangeOfString:@"italic"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:nameFontItalic size:fontSize];
    }
    else
    {
        self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:nameFontRegular size:fontSize];
    }
}
@end
```

I call it with the line:

```
//APPEARANCE
    [[UILabel appearance] setSizedFontName:nil];
```

That works well but I would like to have the same to complete my application with the alert views that seems to escape to that piece of code...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't customize UIAlertView (or UIAlertViewController). It's not recommended. You should if you want customization to do your own Alert.

Comment: you can user Attributed string in your alert. like 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130347/uialertcontroller-set-attributed-messages .   2. https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/05/hacking-uialertcontroller-in-swift.html