# UIAlertView - Set message to Left Alignment in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I am using UIAlertView as below

```
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Review" message:[dictionary valueForKey:@"Review"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
```

[image: Image using default UIAlertView]

UIAlertView using Accessory View

```
    NSMutableString *message = [NSMutableString string];
    NSString *title = [dictionary valueForKey:@"REVIEW"];
    [message appendString:title];
    [message appendString:@"\n"];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Review" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alert setValue:[self getLabelWithMessage:message  withTitle:title] forKey:@"accessoryView"];
    [alert show];
```

[image: UIAlertView - using AccessoryView]

2nd solution working fine for me as per below solution

[Simple UIAlertView with NSAttributedString(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136122/simple-uialertview-with-nsattributedstrings)

But this solution will it approved by Apple?

```
[alert setValue:[self getLabelWithMessage:message  withTitle:title] forKey:@"accessoryView"];
```

I need to set Left Alignment to Message in UIAlertView.

Any suggestions for any other alternative solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: solutions that uses alertView subviews are not working...!

Comment: I though this post was about a few years ago, but it seems it is quite recent so I feel to spoil this, but `UIAlertView` is deprecated since iOS9 – and [`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller) is a new kid on the block.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to highlight that `UIAlertView` is deprecated since iOS 9. Try and use the `UIAlertController`. But that will not serve your purpose of customising the alignment.

Secondly, `UIAlertView`, `UIAlertController`, `UIActionSheet` are considered to be system controls, which means customizing their appearances is not advised. I don't think doing so will affect your review process. But you never know, the Apple reviewers sometimes accept some apps and reject some having the same restricted things. This is why we should stick to the guidelines.