# How To Create Custom view That looks like Alert View?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating one custom uiview control that looks like alert view.
I have user RKRichtexteditor on my custom control.
I can not add my view inside alert control because alert control size is fixed.

## My question is

when I have pressed button my custom view will shows just like alert view.
I have done with using blur effect,
I have facing one problem.
My problem is my tab bar is not blur.

## Image

[image]

```
Code is
=======
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.blureEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
    self.visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:self.blureEffect];
    self.visualEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    self.visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    [self.view addSubview:self.visualEffectView];
```

How to blur my tab bar when my custom control is open.
please help me guys or give me any link.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom view which looks like UIAlertView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118919/custom-view-which-looks-like-uialertview)

Comment: But do not want to use UIAlert view that was my condition.

Comment: currently `UIAlertView` is deprecated (so you can't use it anyway) and `UIAlertController` suppose to be used. There is no way to do extensive customization of `UIAlertController`.

Comment: Please kindly request you  to read question again,I do not want to use Uialert view or UIAlertControlller For my specific requirement thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this.

```
    self.blureEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
    self.visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:self.blureEffect];
    self.visualEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    self.visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:self.visualEffectView];
```

Comment: let me check Thank you

Comment: and just change
 "self.visualEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds;"
"self.visualEffectView.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];"

Comment: :-Not Working ,it shows me my two extra buttons which are placed just top of the tab bar.Thank you

Comment: :-it blured everything including my custom view plus tabbar. :(

Comment: Thanks let me check